# Using <Route> with query string in react-router v5

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

please tell me if there is a possibility in react-router used  with quary string?
For Example

---

> <Route path={'/settings/information?page=1'}
> component={Component} /> <Route path={'/settings/information?page=2'}
> component={Component2} />

---